# Changing object file output path in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a `makefile` which does the following:

```
FILES=file1.c file2.c file3.c subdir1/afile1.c subdir2/bfile1.c
OBJS=$(FILES:.c=.o)
all: $(OBJS)
```

This will write the object files to the same directory as the source files but I don't want that. I want them to be written to separate subdirectories named "objs", "objs/subdir1" and "objs/subdir2" so I've tried the following:

```
OBJS=$(FILES:.c=objs/.o)
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried to create a new rule like so:

```
 %.o: %.c:
     $(CC) -o objs/$@ $(CFLAGS) $*.c
```

But this results in the following error:

```
 Mixed implicit and static pattern rules. Stop.
```

So what is the easiest way to have the object files stored inside an "objs" subdirectory that mirrors the structure of the source file directory? i.e. `file1.o`, `file2.o`... should go into "objs", `afile1.o`should go into "objs/subdir1" and `bfile1.o` should go into "objs/subdir2"?

Comment: The error is because you have an extra colon at the end of your pattern rule.  It should be `%.o: %.c` not `%.o: %.c:`.  However that won't do what you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded to in my comments, if you want targets to be created in a subdirectory you have to tell make that's what you want by modifying your target in your rule... just modifying the compiler command isn't enough because make doesn't know anything about what the recipes are doing.

Write your rule as:

```
OBJS = $(FILES:%.c=objs/%.o)

objs/%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not what you want, but you can change the **source** search path using [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html).